# ¿Cómo hago para permitir un solo uso a la vez en MySQL si dos o más personas acceden al mismo archivo .PHP a hacer uso del INSERT?

Tags: php, html, mysql, php7

muy buen día para todos.

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente código .php, así mismo dos usuarios o más estan en diferentes computadores o dispositivos con la sesión iniciada, en el caso que todos den clic sobre un botón y me ejecute este código, como hago para que se ejecute uno por uno y no todos a la vez, ya que en la base de datos tengo relaciones que me traen datos y hacen unos cálculos y me los vuelve a guardar, el tema es para que cuando se vayan a guardar se haga de forma correcta.

```
<?php
 //Aquí van algunas variables que estoy obteniendo por método POST

$insertar = "INSERT INTO tabla (value1, value2, value3, ...) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', ...)";

if ( $conexion->query( $insertar ) == true ) { ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("Correcto: ..::REGISTRO SATISFACTORIO::..");
    window.location.href="../inasistencias";
    </script>;
<?php } else { ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("Error: ..::SE PRODUJO UN ERROR VUELVA A INTENTARLO::..");
    window.location.href="../inasistencias";
    </script>;
<?php }
?>
```

En resumen, lo que quiero hacer es que si todos los usuarios den clic y ejecutan este código de .php, se haga uno por uno, ya que como menciono anteriormente, estoy afectando tablas a las cuales hago cálculos y si todos dan al mismo tiempo en INSERT, pues la información no sería valida.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizar la consulta como una transacción bloqueando las demás conexiones y verificando la consulta actual.

```
$insertar = "START TRANSACTION ";
$insertar .= "INSERT INTO tabla (value1, value2, value3, ...) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', ...);";
$insertar .= "COMMIT";
```

Comment: Gracias, aún no califico tu respuesta porque aún no la he implementado, ahora la implemento debido a que no estoy en casa. De otro lado me surge la pregunta ¿Si bloqueo las demás transacciones, cuando termine de insertar la actual, las otras se insertan?, ¿No hay problema de que la otra persona recargue la página o algo así por el estilo?

Comment: Una vez se haya verificado la consulta, la sucederá la siguiente encolada en la base de datos

Comment: Este es el código completo, bueno realmente solo el archivo para hacer el INSERT https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uLFTYBn_PTr7BN2WyoHnjmIeoxYsGD6e